# Bare infinitive after "help" with intervening past participle phrase

Tags: participles, bare-infinitive

Which is correct?

> Our mission is to help everyone touched by tragedy thrive.

or

> Our mission is to help everyone touched by tragedy to thrive.

I know that technically help can admit the bare infinitive, but something about the presence of the intervening past participle phrase makes it strike my ear as incorrect. Thoughts?

Comment: Our mission is to  help those touched by the tragedy thrive.

Comment: Purely between your two examples (forgetting about rephrasing) I'd say your first is more natural.

Comment: The verb "help" does (for some speakers at least) permit a bare infinitival complement. But because of the amount of material between the matrix verb "help" and the subordinate verb "thrive", I would stick with the _to_- infinitival in this instance.

Comment: It's not a question of grammar. Both are grammatical, both can mean the same. Dropping the *to* doesn't matter in syntax. However, the sentence reads **better with it**. It's **because of the long noun phrase** "everyone touched by tragedy".  HTH.

Comment: It's not about participles or bare infinitives but about readability. To that extent, this Q belongs on [writers.se]

Answer (score 1):

Both are perfectly acceptable English.

Here are some examples of the construction *help everyone/those*+past participial+bare infinitive. The direct object of *help* is in brackets, while the second verb (the [catenative complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catenative_verb) of *help*) is in its bare infinitival form and in boldface.

*In New York after 9/11 the support of family and friends continues to help [those left behind] **cope** with their loss.* [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=qTLizeF5SgYC&lpg=PA70&dq=%22to%20help%20those%20left%22&pg=PA70#v=onepage&q=%22to%20help%20those%20left%22&f=false)
*To work together to help [everyone affected by severe mental illness] **recover** a better quality of life.* [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=zT5nAQAAQBAJ&lpg=PT74&dq=%22to%20help%20everyone%20affected%22&pg=PT74#v=onepage&q=%22to%20help%20everyone%20affected%22&f=false)

More generally, both the *to-infinitival* and bare infinitival versions are found when the direct object is long.

Some examples of such usage **without** *to,* again from published literature. These examples are different from the ones above in that *those* is followed by a preposition phrase (PP) rather than a past participial:

*The central focus of the Block approach to process consulting is to help [those in the organisation or community] **make** better decisions based on their own resources and understanding of the situation.* [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=7tvEE0OYiRwC&lpg=PA149&dq=%22to%20help%20those%22&pg=PA149#v=onepage&q=%22to%20help%20those%22&f=false)
*There are also heavier weights used to help [those with spastic/tremor problems] **continue** a task.* [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=1pcP_SpHL_EC&lpg=PA32&dq=%22to%20help%20those%22&pg=PA32#v=onepage&q=%22to%20help%20those%22&f=false)

And some examples of usage **with** *to*:

*The effects of these high prices has really caused a lot of debate and discussion in Washington about what we can do to help [those particularly on fixed income and lower incomes] **to meet** their energy needs.* [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=VxwN44525HUC&lpg=PA1&dq=%22to%20help%20those%22&pg=PA1#v=onepage&q=%22to%20help%20those%22&f=false)
*The main goal of this book is to help [those who are in this sometimes thankless role] **to design,** modify, and optimize your backup systems.* [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=0lfehRoBOPkC&lpg=PA1&dq=%22The%20main%20goal%20of%20this%20book%20is%20to%20help%20those%20who%20are%20in%20this%20sometimes%22&pg=PA1#v=onepage&q=%22The%20main%20goal%20of%20this%20book%20is%20to%20help%20those%20who%20are%20in%20this%20sometimes%22&f=false)
*Then I'll offer eight keys to help [those of you with passive-aggressive tendencies] **to find** new ways to relate to your anger and to express your needs to others more directly.* [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=oa5QAQAAQBAJ&lpg=PR15&dq=%22to%20help%20those%22&pg=PR15#v=onepage&q=%22to%20help%20those%22&f=false)

(source)

Answer (score 0):

I think your instinct is correct, because *everyone touched by tragedy* is a longish phrase and has its own verb that could distract a reader from the wider context of the sentence. The presence of *to* provides a clue to help readers get back on track.

You want them to parse the sentence as

> Our mission is to help [everyone touched by tragedy] thrive.

but they might see it as

> Our mission is to help [everyone touched by [tragedy thrive]].

or even

> [Our mission is to help everyone] touched by [tragedy thrive].

neither of which make any sense, so they would need to go back and think again. On the other hand, if the sentence was simply

> Our mission is to help you thrive.

then leaving out the *to* would be fine, if slightly more informal than the other option.